# How to install and use just Clang-Format on Fedora 27?

Tags: c++, clang, code-formatting, clang-format

I'm trying to figure out how to install the [stand alone Clang-Format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) tool.

I've downloaded the pre build binaries for Clang from the [official download page](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) for my OS (Fedora 27).

However I failed to figure out how to run the tool.

The documentation above says `clang-format` is located in `clang/tools/clang-format` however such path doesn't exists in the downloaded files.

I searched the entire downloaded directory for 'format' and found 'clang-format' executable in the /bin/ directory.

However when I try to run it from the terminal like so:
`./clang-format`

The terminal says:
`bash: ./clang-format: No such file or directory`

(I've changed the file permissions to allow execution)

I've also looked into building `clang-format` from source, but I failed to find instructions how to build `clang-format` alone without any other clang additions.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Install clang-tools extra:

```
sudo dnf install clang-tools-extra
```

For Fedora < 32, you just need to install clang, which already bundles the clang-format tool.

```
sudo dnf install clang
```

And if you want to find the location of clang-format.You can use [locate](https://www.tecmint.com/install-locate-command-to-find-files-in-centos/).

```
locate clang-format
```

Comment: Thank you, but shouldn't it also work when you download it from them? Clang-Format should be a stand alone tool.. Why do I need to install all of clang to use it?

Comment: @MichaelFildstein `clang-format` depends on the `libclang-cpp.so` library, I guess to reuse the C++ parser and maybe other syntactic analysis tools. That library takes a large part of the installed size of the `clang-libs` package, which is two orders of magnitude larger than the `clang` package which only packages the binaries. So, while it's possible to carve `clang-format` and/or `libclang-cpp.so` into separate packages, the space savings might not be a game changer.